# Illegal aliens, the string and little fruit?

Tags: weapon, space-exploration, first-contact

In “[Illegal Aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_Aliens_(novel))” the assasin’s weapon of choice is a string and a little fruit. My question is this: how does the assasin use the fruit/string combo or even what the little fruits name is, if it’s mentioned that is?
Does it work a little like a gorrate?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleImplements

Comment: @valorum Probably, although I wonder if the Foglio illustrations might cast some light.